# libxml2 with default sax handler and custom error handler

Tags: c++, libxml2, custom-error-handling

I would like to use a simple libxml2 parser in a C++ program the following way:

1. default sax handler is fine (actually I'd like to avoid the effort of writing my own. I understand that I can do what I want with a custom sax handler)
2. the parser should be embedded in a C++ class that can be instantiated arbitrarily (possibly multi-threaded), the libxml2 parser context as member var
3. there are other components also using libxml2 but out of my control (I cannot
   exactly tell what they do and how they use libxml2)
4. in the C++ class I want to use a custom error handler that does not just prints to stderr but I want to collect the errors and throw an exception

Example:

```
class XmlParser
{
  public:
    XmlDoc * parseText(const char * txt, ...);

  private:
    xmlParserCtxtPtr ctx;

    static void xmlErrorHandler(void * userData, xmlErrorPtr err);
}
```

Here is what does NOT work (to my testing and understanding):

- use xmlSetStructuredErrorFunc() or xmlSetGenericErrorFunc() and set the current C++ instance as user data because these funcs just set a global var (not thread-safe)
- use xmlNewParserCtxt() and set ctx->sax->serror to a regular C++ method - error handler must be static
- same as previous but with a static class method - actually that does work but at the same time I want to set ctx->user_data (to 'this' of the current C++ instance) - that makes the parser crash, it looks as if inside of libxml2 ctx->user_data is passed through the functions where there should be just ctx ... however that happens consistently, i.e. looks rather like a feature than a bug :-)

Now, has anybody an idea how to get this to work?

Many thx!!!

Comment: Quick update: I discovered the '_private' field in xmlParserCtxtPtr which I can use to store 'this' of the C++ instance in the libxml2 ctx and extract it in the error handler (which is a static method). Works nicely ... do I overlook something?